# C++ Template Meta-programming, with variadic templates to perform an operation of specific members of a structure

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, metaprogramming

I devoloped this method whilst finding a way to nicely abstract binding a struct to a SQL statement for a SQLite wrapper, my aim is to be able to abstract away most of the binding process as well as being able to "alias" the specialised function template so that you dont need to retype the bindings on each use.

The method I found will compile on clang but I cant currently get it to work for both GCC and MSVC due to the use of the `auto` keyword this is replicated in the example below with `add_2`.

Example:

```cpp
// final function to perform the addition on each member
template<class T, class M>
void add2_member(T& value, M member)
{
    value.*member += 2;
}

// variadic template function that unpack the Members and calls add2_member for each
// arg in args using c++17 fold syntax.
template<class T, auto T::*... Members>
void add2(T& value)
{
    (add2_member(value, Members), ...);
}

// example struct X
struct X
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

// alias add2 function specialisation
auto add2_x = add2<X, &X::a, &X::c>;

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.a = 2;
    x.c = 1;
    add2_x(x);
}
```

A live link showing this work is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/EgmjhJ) which shows the example in godolt compiling in with Clang 9, but GCC is unable to deduce the type of the auto and I currently have not found a way to achive my goal without it, less this could be done using macro's.

Comment: Is your question whether the code is valid, or if there's a way to get it working on existing compilers?

Comment: gcc's apparent problem is figuring out that `T` is `X`. Adding a forward declaration of `X`, and declaring `template<class T, auto X::*... Members>` makes gcc happy.

Comment: Or, `template<class T, auto ... Members> void add2(T& value)` also seems to work, or, at least, compile.

Comment: Related to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64194, perhaps?

Comment: Yup thank, I'd tried that earlier in the day sillily but had moved to using the more verbose `auto T::*...` over `auto ...` before learning how to use the fold, I'll post the resolved code.

Comment: And also my question was kind of both for whether this is valid C++ or invalid hence the other compilers not handling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution thanks to [Sam Varshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik).

Both MSVC and GCC were now able to compile this code and deduce the auto type, though for MSVC you muse remember to pass `/Zc:auto`.

```cpp
template<class T, class M>
void add2_member(T& value, M member)
{
    value.*member += 2;
}

template<class T, auto ... Members>
void add2(T& value)
{
    (add2_member(value, Members), ...);
}
```